# Delays inside fx queue are not behaving ok

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

I need to implement a text link that triggers a message box.

**Premises**:

- When I click on the link, the box appears from top of the page (unfolding). The box has 0.9 of opacity.
- When the box has opened, it waits 5 seconds and then fades out.
- If I click inside the box while it's open, it fades out.
- If I click on the link (the one that triggered the box) while the box is open, it happens nothing.
- Of course, the user can click many times on the link and

**My approach**:

- At the beggining, I position the box at top:-150px (its height) and make it invisible.
- When the user clicks on the link, I find out if the box is visible. If it's, I do nothing (to meet 4th premise).
- If it's not visible, then I build this fx queue: animate its top position to 0px -> delay of 5 seconds -> fade out -> set its top position to -150px (start position).
- If the user clicks inside the box, I clear fx queue, make the box to fade out and then set its top position to -150px (start position).

**Implementation:**

[link to jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dHYuq/2/)

```
$.extend($.fn, {

    // Method to open the box
    openMessage: function() {
        var elem = $(this);
        if (!elem.is(":visible")) {
            elem.fadeTo(0, 0.9).animate({
                top: 0
            }).delay(10000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                elem.css("top", "-150px");
            });
        }
    },

    // Method to close the box when clicking inside it
    closeOnClick: function() {
        var elem = $(this);

        elem.click(function() {
            elem.clearQueue().fadeOut("fast", function() {
                elem.css("top", "-150px");
            });
        });
    }

});


// Text link opens the box
$("#open_message").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#message").openMessage();
});

// Clicking in the message will close it
$("#message").closeOnClick();
```

**My problem:**

Everything goes ok, the box unfolds, waits 5 seconds and then fades out. Problems come when I click inside the box. It fades out, ok, but from this moment the pauses are lower than 5 seconds. If I don't click inside the box, it always wait 5 sedons, from the moment I click inside the box, the pauses are shorter.

**My question:**
What I'm doing wrong? I guess it's a queue issue, but I can't find where is the mistake.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the issue is where you are doing the delay.  I would use setTimeout/clearTimeout:

```
var t;

$('#link').click(function(){
    showBox();
    t = setTimeout(hideBox, 5000);
});

$('#box').click(function(){
    clearTimeout(t);
    t = setTimeout(hideBox, 5000);
});
```